# double integral on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

I have $Q=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $f: Q\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x,y)= 
\begin{cases}
2xy,  & \text{if }y\in \mathbb{Q} \\
y, & \text{if } y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \\
\end{cases}$$

How can I calculate $\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dx\right)dy$?

Answer (score 0):

The rationals have zero measure, so you only need to integrate over the irrationals.  In this case, you get 1/2.

Comment: f isn't integrable on Q?

Comment: It is integrable, but the Riemann integral of any function over Q is zero.

Comment: I don't understand why f isn't Riemann integrable on Q.How can I prove it?

Comment: $| \int_S f| \leq max|f| \mu(S)$.  And the measure of Q is zero.

Comment: Can i say : if y is rational $\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dx=\int_{0}^{1}2xy dx=y$ and if y is irrational $\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dx=\int_{0}^{1}y dx=y$ so the final integral's value is ${1}\over{2}$?